# Python - Attribute Error - module has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, attributes, python-3.5, attributeerror

I am trying to run a Python script that involves importing other modules and running them.  There were no import errors but when trying to run one of the modules it said that there was an attribute error.  (AttributeError: module EC.ec has no attribute 'run'.)  I have tried changing 'import EC.ec as esiRun' to 'from EC import ec as esiRun' but that resulted in the same error.

Everything runs smoothly for TC and L123.

Why is it saying that module Ec.ec has no attribute 'run'?  How can I fix this?

```
import TC.scrapeItems as tsiRun
import L123.scraper as lsiRun
import EC.ec as esiRun
from scrape_class import DataValidator

class scraper():

    def __init__(self):
        self._dv = DataValidator()

    def tc(self, date):
        data = tsiRun.run(date)
        self._dv.addData(data)

        print("finished")

    def l123(self, date):
        data = lsiRun.run(date)
        self._dv.addData(data)

        print("finished")

    def runDateLimited(self, date):
        self.tc(date)
        self.l123(date)

    def ec(self):
        data = esiRun.run()
        self._dv.addData(data)

        print("finished")

    def runCrawlers(self):
        self.ec()


    @property
    def dataValidator(self):
        return self._dv


def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you link us to the EC package, or is this a private library?

Comment: Have you checked that `EC.ec` actually defines a `run` function? Could you be mistaken about whether it's even supposed to have a `run` function? Also, post the stack trace.